# A Series of Questions About Wordpress Theme Development

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is incredibly useful for those that don't know how to build websites, and kind of annoying but at the same time useful for those that do know how to build websites. I know how to build websites and i started making the effort to learn Wordpress because my internship job prefers that i learn Wordpress. So in an effort to learn Wordpress i want to ask a series of questions about developing Wordpress themes(which is what i need to learn btw).

1: Whats the process of creating a Wordpress theme? Do you first build the full website with HTML and once that's done do you convert it into Wordpress?

2: Does wordpress make website load-speed slower? Splitting an HTML website into seperate files like header.php, footer.php, sidebar.php would make things seem as if they would load slower because each part would need to be called, rather than loading it all in one piece. So does Wordpress slow down page-speed or anything at all?

3: I want to convert my HTML website into a Wordpress website. I don't want to deal with adding customization or anything like that. All i want from wordpress is the CMS which i can use to upload content to my website and thats all. Any changes i want to apply i'll do it with the HTML code. So is it possible to create a wordpress theme without splitting my HTML into header.php, footer.php and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) That's how I do it. I first build my Website as HTML. So I have all the necessary Files (html/css/js). Afterwards I convert it into a Theme

2) If you're using a CMS it's always a bit slower than a static page.

3) Nope. Wordpress needs it own structure. At least you need:

```
footer.php
header.php
style.css
index.php
functions.php
```

Here we go. This tutorial looks pretty good:
http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-theme-html-1/

Answer (score 0):

1) This is the main strategy am following. I feel that this is very simple to convert after build the site in HTML and fix the design issues.

2) Loading speed of wp depends on the load of your design. comparing wp with static HTML site wp slower than HTML site. But using caching plug-ins you can increase the speed of your site.

3) Wp have a its own structure so you can create template for word-press only accepting its own structure. Header and footer is not just a HTML split that contain php function calls for the website. Here in this there is no single page concept, all are just parts and depends on the type they join together and perform the functions. Suppose if you trying to create a template without spiting it should me little difficult to build such good theme for word-press.